# Nextjs export clear "out" folder

Tags: next.js

I'm working with nextjs and this example https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-static-export

in next.config.js i have code:

```
module.exports = {
  async exportPathMap(defaultPathMap, { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId, incremental }) {
    // we fetch our list of posts, this allow us to dynamically generate the exported pages
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=3'
    )
    const postList = await response.json()

    // tranform the list of posts into a map of pages with the pathname `/post/:id`
    const pages = postList.reduce(
      (pages, post) =>
        Object.assign({}, pages, {
          [`/post/${post.id}`]: { page: '/post/[id]' },
        }),
      {}
    )

    // combine the map of post pages with the home
    return Object.assign({}, pages, {
      '/': { page: '/' },
    })
  },
}
```

Its fetch 3 posts and generate files - [id].html - its great!

But now i need to fetch new post and build page only for this new post but commad **next export** remove all files from out and create only one post.

What i need to do to keep old post and add new one on next export?

Example:

- First next export with request for 3 posts from api
- generate 3 post in folder "out"
- change api url and run next export for 1 new post
- summary i have 3 old post pages and 1 new in my "out" directory

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Next can't do this out of the box, but you can set it up to do so. First, you'll need a system (database) of which pages have already been built. Second, you'll need some method of communicating with that database (api) to ask which pages *should* be built (eg, send over a list of pages and the api responds telling you which ones have not yet bene built). Then, tell your `exportPathMap` which pages to build. And finally, move your built pages out of `out` and into a new final/public directory.

By default, Next will build/export anything in the `pages` directory plus anything you set in `exportPathMap`, and put all of those in the `out` directory. You can override *what* it builds by passing a custom `exportPathMap`, and how you handle what goes into the `out` directory is up to you, so you can move those files to a different actual public directory and merge them with the old files.